# Convert YYYYMMDD to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I need to join some order dates from two different queries (drawn from linked access databases). In Query 1, the date is formatted like YYYYMMDD, no slashes or hyphens. I don't think access can recognize this as a date. Query 2 has dates in the format, MM/DD/YYYY I would like to change the order dates in Query 1 to.

I am not sure how to start doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
DateSerial(Left([DateColumn],4),Mid([DateColumn],5,2),Right([DateColumn],2))
```

Comment: How do I incorporate this into the SQL statement?

Comment: @AngelaTran:- In which SQL statement you want this to be used? Please provide some more details!

Comment: I want to make a full join statement and match the converted date column on Query 1 with the date column on Query 2. Would this be in a WHERE clause?

Comment: @AngelaTran:- Yes it would be there in the WHERE clause.

Comment: thank u! I made a new column instead of WHERE clause to simplify things

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(nvarchar(50), date from query1, 107)
```

It will give you date format mm-DD-yyyy.